# SQL Server unique auto-increment column in the context of another column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, auto-increment

Suppose the table with two columns:

```
ParentEntityId int foreign key
Number int
```

`ParentEntityId` is a foreign key to another table.

`Number` is a *local* identity, i.e. it is unique within single `ParentEntityId`.

Uniqueness is easily achieved via unique key over these two columns.

**How to make `Number` be automatically incremented in the context of the `ParentEntityId` on insert?**

---

**Addendum 1**

To clarify the problem, here is an abstract.

`ParentEntity` has multiple `ChildEntity`, and each `ChiildEntity` should have an unique incremental `Number` in the context of its `ParentEntity`.

---

**Addendum 2**

Treat `ParentEntity` as a **Customer**.

Treat `ChildEntity` as an **Order**.

So, orders for every customer should be numbered 1, 2, 3 and so on.

Comment: Please clarify 'in the context of it's parent entity' in sql terms... 
The only context is that of the table a record resides in. Relations are achieved via FK constraints and you already have one, if in fact 1:M is what you are after.

What is the purpose of the 'context sensitive' Number?

Comment: @Sky: please, take a look at Addendum 2. Hope it clarifies the intention.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, there's no native support for this type of column, but you could implement it using a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_MyTable_Number
ON MyTable
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

BEGIN TRAN;

WITH MaxNumbers_CTE AS
(
    SELECT ParentEntityID, MAX(Number) AS Number
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE ParentEntityID IN (SELECT ParentEntityID FROM inserted)
)
INSERT MyTable (ParentEntityID, Number)
    SELECT
        i.ParentEntityID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER
        (
            PARTITION BY i.ParentEntityID
            ORDER BY (SELECT 1)
        ) + ISNULL(m.Number, 0) AS Number
    FROM inserted i
    LEFT JOIN MaxNumbers_CTE m
        ON m.ParentEntityID = i.ParentEntityID

COMMIT
```

Not tested but I'm pretty sure it'll work.  If you have a primary key, you could also implement this as an `AFTER` trigger (I dislike using `INSTEAD OF` triggers, they're harder to understand when you need to modify them 6 months later).

Just to explain what's going on here:

- `SERIALIZABLE` is the strictest isolation mode; it guarantees that only one database transaction at a time can execute these statements, which we need in order to guarantee the integrity of this "sequence."  Note that this irreversibly promotes the entire transaction, so you won't want to use this inside of a long-running transaction.
- The CTE picks up the highest number already used for each parent ID;
- `ROW_NUMBER` generates a unique sequence for each parent ID (`PARTITION BY`) starting from the number 1; we add this to the previous maximum if there is one to get the new sequence.

I probably should also mention that if you only ever need to insert one new child entity at a time, you're better off just funneling those operations through a stored procedure instead of using a trigger - you'll definitely get better performance out of it.  This is how it's currently done with `hierarchyid` columns in SQL '08.

Comment: @Aaronaught: yes, I'm goning to have an identity primary key. How would this code be simplified in the case of `AFTER` trigger? To be honest, I don't fully understand your `INSTEAD OF` trigger code.

Comment: @Anton: I wouldn't say making it an `AFTER` trigger simplifies, exactly - it just changes the `INSERT` into an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN`.  But `INSTEAD OF` triggers have various annoying limitations, i.e. you can only have one per table, and it always looks weird to me re-inserting the `inserted` data.  But that's how it works.  Hopefully the annotations I added help you understand it better.

Comment: Thank you, @Aaronaught. I'm going to use trigger as you'd suggested. Accepting.

Answer (score 2):

Need add `OUTPUT` clause to trigger for Linq to SQL сompatibility.

For example:

```
INSERT MyTable (ParentEntityID, Number)
OUTPUT inserted.* 
SELECT
  i.ParentEntityID,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER
  (
   PARTITION BY i.ParentEntityID
   ORDER BY (SELECT 1)
  ) + ISNULL(m.Number, 0) AS Number
FROM inserted i
LEFT JOIN MaxNumbers_CTE m
ON m.ParentEntityID = i.ParentEntityID
```

Answer (score 0):

This solves the question as I understand it: :-)

```
DECLARE @foreignKey int
SET @foreignKey = 1  -- or however you get this

INSERT Tbl (ParentEntityId, Number) 
VALUES (@foreignKey, ISNULL((SELECT MAX(Number) FROM Tbl WHERE ParentEntityId = @foreignKey), 0) + 1)
```

Comment: Does this approach guarantee a thread safety? I mean won't there appear two records with the same `Number` value? Probably, it should be done in a trigger...

Comment: @roufamatic: Anton is asking if it is possible to increment the number **automatically**.  Calling `select MAX(...)` doesn't look like an automatic number generation according to how i understood the question

Comment: @Anton -- we can surround this with an applock for thread safety.
@Sung Meister -- I agree to disagree on the definition of "automatic." :-) This automatically updates the Number field when called.