# MSSQL Can a column auto-increment only under certain circumstances

Tags: sql-server, conditional-statements, auto-increment

I have a table with 4 columns ID, c1, c2 and LOT. ID is the primary key. For every record when c1 is 5 I want to auto-generate a number for LOT which will be a sequence starting from 1 for each distinct value of c2.

So if c1 is not 5, LOT remains null. But if c1 is 5 then for every record where c2=1 I want to populate LOT with an auto-incrementing sequence starting from 1. 
Ex:

```
ID  c1  c2  LOT
1   3   
2   5   1   1
3   5   1   2
4   5   1   3
5   4
```

Then do the same for a different value of c2. So if c2 is 2, have another bunch of auto-incrementing LOT numbers starting from 1:

```
ID  c1  c2  LOT
6   3   
7   5   2   1
8   5   1   4
9   5   2   2
10  5   2   3
```

We are using MSSQL 2014 Enterprise Ed. Would table-partitioning be useful or do I need to create special tables for each distinct value of C2?

Comment: Sorry I don't see a reference to triggers in that link.

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong link previously.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/24335341/1072229 for a similar discussion.

Comment: Thanks. That looks relevant. I also found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205036/sql-server-unique-auto-increment-column-in-the-context-of-another-column?rq=1 from the sidebar that also addresses this using a trigger that explains my concern below (about uniqueness)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the suggestions to use a trigger (all up-voted). It turns out (as I mentioned in a comment above) an article that came up on the side-bar ([SQL Server unique auto-increment column in the context of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205036/sql-server-unique-auto-increment-column-in-the-context-of-another-column?rq=1)) shows a detailed construction of the proper INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger. The author mentions that it is "Not tested", and indeed there IS a slight error (a missing GROUP BY ParentEntityID in the WITH clause) but anybody copying the code would get an error that is obvious to fix. Probably not kosher to be correcting that post here, but the other question is 6 years old.

Answer (score 1):

not with an identity field, you can use a trigger instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of doing this using the Identity feature, however, consider using a [Instead of trigger](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521(v=sql.105).aspx) to manually manage the values like you want.

Comment: I guess I don't see how triggers can be guaranteed to generate unique unbroken sequences. How do you solve the problem of multiple simultaneous inserts?

Comment: I don't know how you'd get around the issue of simultaneous inserts, but I don't think there really is any way to guarantee that without using the engine's identity

Comment: Actually, in the post I mention in "my own" answer below, the trigger code uses SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE which the author says guarantees an unbroken unique sequence (but with some potential performance issues.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the logic to generate LOT in a query or view:

```
SELECT ID, C1, C2,
    CASE
        WHEN C1<>5 OR C2 IS NULL THEN NULL
        ELSE COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY C1, C2 ORDER BY ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
    END AS LOT
 FROM D
 ORDER BY ID
```

Given a table generated with (ID, C1, C2):

```
CREATE TABLE D (ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, C1 INT, C2 INT)
INSERT D VALUES (3,NULL),
                (5,1),
                (5,1),
                (5,1),
                (4,NULL),
                (3,NULL),
                (5,2),
                (5,1),
                (5,2),
                (5,2)
```

The query produces the output indicated above:

```
ID  C1  C2  LOT
1   3   
2   5   1   1
3   5   1   2
4   5   1   3
5   4   
6   3   
7   5   2   1
8   5   1   4
9   5   2   2
10  5   2   3
```

The statement used to generate `LOT`, `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY C1, C2 ORDER BY ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`, simply counts the number of rows before and including the current row where C1 and C2 are equal to the current row.  For instance, for Row 4, the tuple (c1,c2)=(5,1) is observed in 3 records before and including that row (rows 2, 3, and 4), so LOT=3.